# How to obtain IP address of new user when they sign up in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a an ip_addr column for my users table.  I have a signup page in which the user can enter a username, email, and password and it saves the data.  I also want to obtain the IP address when a new user creates an account.  Is there a simple way to go about doing this?  I have been playing with request.remote_ip with no luck.  Any ideas on how I could place this in my users_controller.rb?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  invisible_captcha only: [:create], honeypot: :spam_detected

  def spam_detected
    redirect_to 'http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/'
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    if User.exists?(name: params[:user][:name])  # you can change :name to :email/etc
      redirect_to '/articles?username_email_already exists'
    else
      user = User.new(user_params)
      if user.save
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to '/'
      else
        redirect_to '/signup'
      end
    end
  end
private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :ip_addr)
  end

end
```

Comment: what is the error you see ? tried printing it out ?

Comment: a lot simpler solution is to just use `Devise` if you are interested in getting all these details anyway

Comment: May I ask what your motivation for capturing the ip address at sign up is?

Comment: I plan to use devise on my next app.  Right now I'm just wanting to do things from scratch since I'm new.  I really have no use for grabbing the IP.  Im just curious and trying different things in case I need something to reference in the future.  I'm creating a personal site and going through examples.

Comment: ah I see - curiosity is good :) Just bear in mind that IP's aren't static and can change from session to session or even during a session, so shouldn't be used as a mechanism for identifying users - but I'm sure you have considered that anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def create
  if User.exists?(name: params[:user][:name]) # should definitely be :email
    redirect_to '/articles'
  else
    user = User.new(user_params)
    user.ip_addr = request.remote_ip # <= added
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end
end
```

You don't need to send `ip_addr` through the form (i.e. `user_params`), just handle this within the request.

Also, I would assign the users ip on login, since it might change from session to session.

Comment: Just curious, why is best to verify using the email address instead of name?

Comment: People can easily have the same name, however email address must be unique by their nature. Two John Smiths using Hotmail will never have the same email address (e.g. `johnsmith@hotmail.com`, `johnsmith2@hotmail.com`). Plus email addresses also have conditions around case sensitivity that can be relied on.